# Can not call interceptor when using @AutoConfigureAfter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class) and annotation-driven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor, spring-annotations

While implementing the interceptors in my spring boot application I came across a weird problem which is as follows:
My Application class code:

```
  @Import(CommonConfig.class)
  @EnableAsync
  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableSwagger2
  @EnableScheduling
  @EnableSpringDataWebSupport
  @ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml" })
  @AutoConfigureAfter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       .......
        ................
    }
@Bean
public TokenInterceptor intializeTokenInterceptor() {
    System.out.println("Adding interceptors");
    return new TokenInterceptor();
}

@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            System.out.println("Adding interceptors");
            registry.addInterceptor(intializeTokenInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
            super.addInterceptors(registry);
        }
    };
}

}
```

Inside my application-context I have mentioned tag (mvc:annotation-driven) as I need this for initializing my bean classes.

Now, if I test my application by removing the annotation-driven tag, my interceptors are getting called. However, if I keep this tag, my interceptors are not getting called, (which I believe is overriding the implementation of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter bean from WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class somehow).

Comment: Remove the tag and `@EnableWebMvc` you are using Spring Boot but disabling all the auto configuration features by adding the explicit configuration. The same applies to the `@AutoConfigureAfter` remove it as it doesn't add anything. And finally why are you still loading an xml file?

Comment: I have application-context because I have security related configurations , along with mongo bean configurations

Comment: And why do you need xml for that? That can perfectly well be done in Java as well. Next to that Spring Boot can auto configure mongo for you. Nonetheless you are disabling the auto web configuration by trying to configure it yourself. Remove those (as stated in my initial comment) and only register the interceptor.